# How To Store Extension in a variable-Asterisk PBX

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

Does anyone know how to store the extension of an incoming caller (caller provisioned on the PBX) in a variable. I need to do this within the asterisk dialplan just after the call is answered.

```
;Answer call
exten => 1234,1,Answer()

;Store caller's extension in a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should parse sip header, this might be what you want

```
exten => 1234,1,Answer()
 same => n,Set(FROM=${CUT(SIP_HEADER(From),@,1)})
 same => n,Set(EXT=${CUT(FROM,:,2)})
 same => n,NoOp(ext: ${EXT})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Set(_CALLERPEERNAME=${CHANNEL(peername)});
```

The underscore character will allow that variable to be inherited.